# Spaces and carriage returns are being added to HTML email

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, iis-6, windows-server-2012

We have a server generated HTML file (`myFile.html`) that we embed in emails that get sent to our clients. We've been using this method for years with minimal issues. We use Windows Server 2012 with smtp server via II6. Recently the HTML is getting skewed in the email. When checking the source file, all looks well. Directly opening the HTML file for viewing in a browser works as you'd expect. Here is the code we're using to read the file into memory to prepare for emailing:

```
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFilePath)
        Do While objFile.AtEndOFStream <>True
            line = objFile.ReadLine
            If Instr(1, line, "<table") > 0 And strHeaderWritten = "N" Then
                strHeaderWritten = "Y"
                strFileContent=strFileContent & strHeader
            End If
            strFileContent=strFileContent & line
        Loop
        set objFile = Nothing
```

And then we add the content to the email and send:

```
    strBody = strFileContent
    Set objMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

    Set objMail.Configuration = cdoConfig
    objMail.From = strFrom
    objMail.ReplyTo = strReplyTo
        
    objMail.To = strTo
    
    objMail.Subject = strSubject
    objMail.HTMLBody = strBody

    objMail.Fields("urn:schemas:httpmail:importance").Value = strImportance
    objMail.Send
```

And here are examples of what it spits out in the email. There are no errors in the source:
[image]

Has anyone else had this happen to them?

Been toiling over this for hours looking for an explanation. Thank so much for reading!

I tried using the ADO Stream method for the email, but it is still coming out the same:

```
        Dim objStream
        Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        objStream.Type = 2 'adTypeText
        objStream.CharSet = Application("CharacterSet")
        objStream.Open
        objStream.LoadFromFile strFilePath

        Do While Not objStream.EOS
            line = objStream.ReadText(-2)
            If Instr(1, line, "<table") > 0 And strHeaderWritten = "N" Then
                strHeaderWritten = "Y"
                strFileContent=strFileContent & strHeader
            End If
            If Instr(1, line, "< table") > 0 Then
                strFileContent=strFileContent & "<h3>Broken HTML</h3>"
            End If
            strFileContent=strFileContent & line
        Loop
        objStream.Close
        Set objStream = Nothing
```

As you can see, I also added a check for one of the persistent errors I'm seeing where there has been a `space` inserted between `<` and `table`. Checking the output this way did not capture the issue as in checking the text for the added space. So it must be happening after it's been written or I need to use a regex for the test. I'll try that next. I'm still seeing it in multiple email clients. Here's an example post test of ADO Stream:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the stream buffer isn’t being reset correctly which is bleeding into the next output, but as for why I’m not sure. Maybe you could try using `ADODB.Stream` instead to read the file in as that has better support for various charsets.

Comment: I'll try that out tomorrow and respond. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I tried this to no avail. I got the same result. Really odd.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question and show how you tried the `ADODB.Stream` method?

Comment: Edited with latest findings.

Comment: So it looks like the string is in order when you create it, but it gets skewed when you add it to the objMail.HTMLBody property, is that correct? Can you try adding vbCrLf after every line you create in the objfile, so it's not one long string?

Comment: I will try this as well and report back. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a common problem in CDO. I've found a few references online to the problem that spaces are randomly inserted into the HTMLbody.

One answer was to make the HTML body not one long string, because CDO will then insert random spaces, but to include whitespace yourself, so that CDO doesn't have to.
You could try adding `VbCrLf` or just plain spaces in the text you're sending.

A second suggestion made more sense to me; this can be an *encoding* problem. That also explains why adding your own whitespace could be a workaround.
Anyway; CDO allows for setting the encoding of the CDO.Message object before sending.
Try `objMail.BodyPart.ContentTransferEncoding = "quoted-printable"` to see if that solves it.

Comment: And we have a winner!

`objMail.BodyPart.ContentTransferEncoding = "quoted-printable"`

did the trick. Thanks a ton! Lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is windows use of both line break and carrage return. I recommend loading the body of the text and replacing all instances of vbcrlf with just vblf and you will find you wont have the double spacing anymore.

e.g.

```
body = replace(body, vbcrlf, vblf)
```